# apodictic vs. apodeictic

Tags: etymology, orthography, greek

Looking through the *Oxford Dictionary for Writers and Editors* (part of the *Oxford Style Manual*, I was suprised to read in its dictionary part the following entry on page 619a:

> **apodictic** clearly established, *not* -deictic

The Oxford Dictionaries entry for [*apodictic*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/apodictic) says the etymology is:

> via Latin from Greek *apodeiktikos,* from *apodeiknunai* 'show off,
>   demonstrate'.

Is there *any* reason other than simple convention why the *Oxford Dictionary for Writers and Editors* recommends writing "apodictic" despite the etymological origin of the word?

Comment: Worrying about conformity to earlier versions rather than modern usage is the etymological fallacy. [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=apodeictic%2Capodictic&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Capodeictic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Capodictic%3B%2Cc0) seem to indicate that ODWE has correctly identified the more popular current variant. The situation seemed to be reversed only around 1890. ODWE should perhaps hedge more carefully (but you don't provide its policy on wording); I'd prefer 'preferred to' to '_not_'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: As a side remark: if that is "the etymological fallacy", then that fallacy does not seem to be as bad a thing as most fallacies are. Just because some (possibly uneducated) majority spells some word some peculiar way does not entail that this spelling ought to be preferred. (Of course, in the current case, the majority probably was not uneducated.)

Comment: I disagree almost totally. A non-hypocritical 'must use the original' claimer shouldn't even be speaking English.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: You should read your own comment: you were talking about "*worrying* about conformity to" -- not about a stubborn *adherence to* -- earlier versions. Worrying is almost never a bad thing.

Comment: Please include the research you've done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references (here, checking in reputable dictionaries and using ngrams) are off-topic. You can check back to see the wealth of opinion on ELU that English needs a largely descriptivist rather than prescriptivist approach.

Comment: I'm also not in favour of the 'Have you stopped beating your wife yet?' nature of  'Is there any reason why the Oxford Dictionary for Writers and Editors recommends writing _apodictic_ other than insufficiently[sic] knowledge of the etymology of the word ...?'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: please, what is your problem? suməlic has given a fine reason in his/her answer. So, yes, there is indeed a reason other than insufficiently [oops] knowledge … asoasf.

Comment: Indeed, I really find suməlic's answer informative and am convinced that any question which bears an informative answer was a question worth asking.

Comment: @ClintEastwood: Well, Edwin Ashworth listed some specific problems with his last two comments. You might not agree with them, but I thought it was worth addressing his criticisms, so I made an edit to your question. Please review it to see if you find it acceptable.

Comment: @ClintEastwood - no, a good answer will not make up for a poor, unresearched and off-topic question.

Comment: @Josh61: Jesus, Josh -- relax!

Comment: @suməlic That's a vast improvement, removing the negative strong-connotation-at-least. However, 'via Latin from Greek apodeiktikos' does highlight the problem about the finer details of the entry of the word into the English lexicon. Does 'via' indicate that the Latin e-less version was first accepted, or merely that the Latin version was heard spoken and the nearer-the-Greek spelling thought more appropriate? But in essence, this question ...

Comment: is posted to challenge descriptivism: 'Just because some (possibly uneducated) majority spells some word some peculiar way does not entail that this spelling ought to be preferred.' It addresses, in the first instance, the correctness of modern usage and style recommendations ('Is there any reason other than simple convention why the Oxford Dictionary for Writers and Editors recommends writing "apodictic" ... ').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - You forget that this is Oxford speaking.  Even God obeys Oxford.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, style manuals don't need a reason beyond simple convention. Some people just like consistency, and to achieve that, you have to prescribe some standard and proscribe the alternatives, even if they're legitimate variants in general. And as [Edwin Ashworth](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/344919/apodictic-vs-apodeictic/344925?noredirect=1#comment797744_344919) points out in a comment, *apodictic* seems to be the more commonly used spelling, which can be considered a reason to prefer it.

There's nothing etymologically wrong with either *apodictic* or *apodeictic.* They just use different conventions for transliterating Greek ει.

Josh61's quote from the Online Etymology Dictionary is informative:

***[apodictic](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=apodictic)***:

> - "clearly demonstrated," 1650s, from Latin *apodicticus*, from Greek *apodeiktikos*

The transliteration with *i* dates back to how the Romans romanized Greek words.

From Wikipedia: [Romanization of Greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Greek)

> Traditional English renderings of Greek names originated from Roman
>   systems established in antiquity. [...] ⟨ει⟩ and ⟨ου⟩ were simplified to ⟨i⟩ (more rarely—corresponding to an earlier pronunciation—⟨e⟩) and ⟨u⟩.

This talks about names, but the same applies to words that originated in Greek but came into English via a Latin intermediary: consider *[irony](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=irony&allowed_in_frame=0),* from Latin *ironia,* from Greek *εἰρωνεία (eironeia).*

The transliteration with *ei* is more letter-by-letter and occurs more frequently with names or with terms that were coined in English directly from Greek roots.

Comment: This makes sense. In that case the Latinisation of Greek terms, of course, would follow the pronunciation which long ago began to pronounce *ει* as "i".

Comment: @ClintEastwood: right. One detail that I didn't get into here is that in Latin, Greek "ει" specifically corresponded to "long i," not "short i." That isn't relevant to the English pronunciation of this word, since Latin vowels of any length are pronounced short in English before a consonant cluster like "ct." But it is relevant for the traditional English pronunciations of some other words or names, like "Darius" from Greek Δαρεῖος, which is traditionally pronounced /dəˈraɪəs/ "duh-RYE-us."

Comment: @suməlic I had never come across _apodictic_ before, but if I'd seen it used, I would probably have assumed it to be a typo for _apodeictic_. Appealing to consistency seems to me rather counter-intuitive, since consistency is exactly why I'd expect it to have _ei_: it's so obviously from the same source as _deixis_ and _deictic_ (and other compounds with those words). The oddness of _apodictic_ is really in its pronunciation, since all other words (that I know of) that include _deictic_ do in fact have a diphthong in English, rather than the short _pit_ vowel.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet:  Apparently "apodixis" also existed once, though the OED suggests it is now obsolete. There's no real consistency with the spelling of this particular root, but "apodictic" is not so unusual if you compare it to other roots from Greek. I think spelling often precedes pronunciation for words like this.