# Eponymous adjective formation

Tags: etymology, adjectives, linguistics, philology, bilingual

I’m writing an essay on Homer’s *Odyssey,* and I was wondering whether the correct adjectival form would be Odysseian or Odyssean according to etymology, as I’ve seen both used in academic contexts. I know that, for example, Plato becomes Platonic because of the Greek suffix -ikos (and in Greek Plato is Plauton), but does the ian/ean formation come from somewhere?

This leads me into some broader questions: is there a rule that *y* should become *i* when used with the -an suffix (I’ve seen both Tolsoyan and Tolstoian, but I’ve only seen Shelleyan a is this a Russian thing?). If there is, where does this come from? I’ve also seen Marlowe become Marlovian or Thoreaux become Thoreauvian - does this *v* sound have a source in a root language? And, interestingly, Foucault becomes Foucauldian, and I’m guessing that this might come from the morphological changes in French?

Would greatly appreciate if someone with knowledge of etymology/linguistics could help me uncover the oddities of eponymous adjective formation. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any governing principles here.  People just grasp at what analogous forms they happen to know about.

Answer (score 4):

The formation of adjectives from names is sometimes (although not always) based on etymology. When not based on etymology, analogy with other adjectives can play a role. As Greg Lee mentioned, there are no firm principles about the formation of such adjectives.

Adjectives ending in *ian, -eian, -ean* tend to come from Latin adjectives ending in *-ius, -eius, -eus,* which in turn may come from Greek adjectives ending in *-ιος* or *-ειος.*

Ancient Greek seems to have an adjective [Ὀδύσσειος](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3D*)odu%2Fsseios) which can anglicized as *Odysseian, Odyssean* or *Odyssian.* Because [Greek ει was Romanized in multiple ways](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/344925/77227), it can correspond to any of *ei, e* or *i* in an English word: there is no strict rule about which form is "correct". The [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Odyssean%2C+Odysseian%2C+Odyssian&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2COdyssean%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2COdysseian%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2COdyssian%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2COdyssean%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2COdysseian%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2COdyssian%3B%2Cc0) seems to show that the spelling with *-ean* is more common.

#### The use of *-yan* vs. *-ian*

In English, final *-y* tends to be a contextual replacement for the letter *-i.* When that is the case, related words are usually spelled with *i* in non-final contexts, unless there is a preceding vowel letter. There are alternations not only with latinate suffixed forms (like *territorial* vs. *territory,* or *colonial* vs. *colony*), but also with English inflected forms such as *bellies* from *belly* or *bloodied* from *bloody.*

When there is a preceding vowel letter, it is regular for the spelling with *y* to be retained in English inflected forms: *saying, keys.* In latinate suffixed forms, the spelling is not very predictable. Depending on the etymology of the word or name, a related adjective could end in *-ian, yan,* or even *-jan* (*Troy, Trojan*). The spelling *Tolstoian* might be partially based on the alternative romanization *Tolstoi.*

However, the name *Shelley* is not romanized, but the OED says that a spelling variant *Shelleian* exists aloongside *Shelleyan.* Likewise, both *Bradleian* and *Bradleyan* seem to be used as adjectives from the name *Bradley.* And on the other hand, some names ending in a consonant and *-y* have adjectives that can be spelled with *-yan;* e.g. *Chomskyan* exists alongside *Chomskian.* So I'm not sure that there's any definite rule about when to use *-yan* vs. *-ian* in the spelling of such words.

#### The use of *-vian*

V is a Latinization of a [w]-like sound. It occurs in some *ian* adjectives when the preceding vowel sounds something like [u] (e.g. *Peru, Peruvian*) or [o], or when the vowel just has a spelling with *w* (as with the digraph *aw,* e.g. *Shaw* > *Shavian*).

#### *Foucauldian*

*Foucauldian* is very strangely formed. Apparently, the *Dictionary of American Family Names* says the last part of the name *Foucault* is from an element *wald* "rule" ([Ancestry.com](https://www.ancestry.com/name-origin?surname=foucault)); I wonder whether that has something to do with the *d* spelling of the related adjective. *Foucaultian* does also seem to have some usage. I found a mailing list discussion where a user suggested the form *[Foucauldian](https://foucault.info/foucault-l/msg00817.html)* is used for "euphonic" reasons, which doesn't make that much sense to me: there are many English words with *t* in the middle. It's true though that it is not usual for a word to end in *-ltian* specifically. A Google search reveals that a few people have used *Rooseveldian* instead of *Rooseveltian,* which seems similar.

*Rimbaud* has the adjective *Rimbaldian,* which doesn't have the *t* to *d* change but which ends in the same *-ldian* sequence.